# Using a java object outside of a method that is in a separate class

Tags: java, swing, object

This is a bit confusing to articulate, but I'll do my best. I have 3 Classes that matter here: Art.java, AddArtGUI.java, and GUI.java. Art.java creates an Art object with several attributes but doesn't do anything with it. GUI.java is what we run and it creates the AddArtGUI that prompts the user to create a new art object with user-provided attributes. AddArtGUI creates a new art object every time it is run but then I can't do anything with it. I need to be able to click "done" and have addArtGUI store the object somewhere so that it can be accessed by other methods (like a viewArt method) later. I also need to be able to run AddArtGui and create more art objects afterwards.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
package jz.art;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Art {
    private String name;
    private String artist;
    private ArrayList<String> tags;

    //constructor
    public Art(String artName, String artistName){
        //various attributes
        name = artName;
        artist = artistName;
        tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //things for use in later methods
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }

    public void addKeyword(String p){
        tags.add(p);
    }

    public boolean matches(String v){
        for(int i = 0; i<tags.size(); i++){
            if(tags.get(i)==v){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And AddArtGUI:

```
package jz.art;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class AddArtGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AddArtGUI
     */
    public AddArtGUI() {
        initComponents();
        System.out.println("---AddArt Opened---");
    }

    /**
**//initialize form method went here.**                    

    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String attributes = tagsField.getText();
        String[] splitTags = attributes.split(", ");

        Art a = new Art(artNameField.getText(), artistNameField.getText());

        for(int i = 0; i<splitTags.length; i++){
            a.addKeyword(splitTags[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Sucessfully added a piece with the following attrubtes:");
        System.out.println("Name: "+artNameField.getText());
        System.out.println("Artist: "+artistNameField.getText());
        System.out.println("Tags: "+Arrays.toString(splitTags));
        this.dispose();
        System.out.println("---AddArt Closed---");

    }                                            

**//main method and look/feel setting code were here**

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel ArtNameTitel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ArtistNameTitile;
    private javax.swing.JLabel TagsNameTitle;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Title;
    private javax.swing.JTextField artNameField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField artistNameField;
    private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
    private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler2;
    private javax.swing.JButton submitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tagsField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

To recap: I need to be able to store the Art a object outside of the AddArtGUI method. Any ideas?

Edit: should I use an arrayList of Art objects?

Comment: an arrayList of Art objects in addArtGUI is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: So, I've added     public ArrayList<Art> allArt; in the addArtGUI and allArt.add(a); to the submit button method and now it is returning a monstrous nullPointerException even if I have stuff in the GUI fields, and it points to the allArt.add(a) statement. Any ideas?

Comment: *Nothing is static -- not sure if this is relevant but ive never understood static so for all I know it may be the problem.

Comment: Did you make sure to initialize allArt before you tried adding objects to it? In your form initialization you need to make sure you also do that: `allArt = new ArrayList<Art>();`

Comment: bingo! can't believe that I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an Art object member to your AddArtGUI class, and set this member instead of using the local variable in the submitButtonActionPerformed method.